# To combine sort and consolidate multiple input files(fixed space separated txt file with 42 columns) with more than 2 million records(lines) in total

Tags: java, jdbc, collections, odbc, ms-access-2007

i am working with two million records in the form of multiple input files(fixed space separated with 45 columns) i have to sort them and then consolidate them together, previously i was working with array lists, generating beans storing in these array lists, sorting and consolidating, it worked fine when the records were less but when i combined all the input files, it threw heap space memory exception .
Now I started using a database MS Access to counter this and read and put all my input files in the access tables using JDBC ODBC connection ,now this alone is taking 5 hours to read the files and store them in DB 
I have to combine and sort theses files as well

Please point me towards the right direction 
To combine sort and consolidate multiple input files with more than 2 million records and generate the output file based on the specification

Answer (score 0):

For starters you could look into a more robust database. [`MySQL`](https://www.mysql.com/) (or a fork of it, [`MariaDB`](https://mariadb.org/)) should be better suited to work with the volume of data you are after.

Reading the files could also be done asynchronously, that should further speed up the process.

As an extra note, depending on what type of consolidation you are after, you could also look into [`External Sorting`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting) algorithms, which are explicitly designed to sort data which does not all fit in memory.